# "I went for a run" - how to say this in Japanese?

Tags: word-choice, translation

I'm an amateur runner and I'm struggling a bit with Japanese vocabulary on the topic of running. The phrase that gives me special trouble is "go for a run". I'm not sure how to convey the meaning of running as training in Japanese. Let's say I want to say

> I go for a run every morning.

So far I tried:

> 毎朝ジョギングしている。

Well, in English jogging is a slow run, not really training. Is it the same in Japanese?

> 毎朝走っている。

Is 走る suitable here? Isn't it just describing the action of running, not conveying the idea of training?

> 毎朝走りこんでいる。

Someone told me 走りこむ is more suitable to describe training. Is that true?

What would be the best phrase to describe "going for a run"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've heard the straight-up katakana ランニング used in this way before.  The following example sentence from 大辞泉 seems to support that as well:

> 健康のため毎朝ランニングをする。

Here are the definitions for ランニング and ジョギング, per 大辞林:

> **ランニング**
> 走ること。
>
> **ジョギング**
> ゆっくり走ること。競走前のウォーミング-アップ，気分転換や健康のために行われる。

Based on the definitions as written, it would appear that the same distinctions between the two words are maintained in Japanese.

Comment: Is it the same as in English that ランニング has more serious meaning (in terms of effort, pace) than ジョギング? The quoted sentence would make sense when either was used.

Comment: Comparing the 大辞林 definitions, ラニング is defined simply as 走ること, whereas it qualifies ジョギング as *ゆっくり*走ること, and then provides an example along the lines of warming up before a race.  So it would appear that the same distinctions are present.

Comment: Thanks. ラニング now seems so obvious that I don't know how I didn't think about it. Can you move the quoted definitions from the comment to the answer and I'll accept it.